# The destination queue '<QueueName>@<servername>' could not be found

Tags: nservicebus

While testing the pub/sub model, I changed the name of the subscriber queue, while the subscription for the old queue still exists in the DB, so there is a dangling subscription in the DB.

So when publisher and subscriber started and I tried to send message from publisher, following exception happened and basically publisher stopped and no longer send any more message

2011-02-09 09:56:21,115 [6] ERROR Publisher.ServerEndpoint [(null)] <(null)> - Problem occurred when starting the endpoint.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The destination queue 'StoreInputQueue@' could not be found. You may have misconfigured the destination for this kind of message (Message.EventMessage) in the MessageEndpointMappings of the UnicastBusConfig section in your configuration file.It may also be the case that the given queue just hasn't been created yet, or has been deleted. ---> System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_WriteHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeSendMessage(MQPROPS properties, IntPtr transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SendInternal(Object obj, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Send(Object obj, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport.Send(TransportMessage m, String destination) in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5f701adefe8f8\src\impl\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast.Msmq\MsmqTransport.cs:line 334
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Msmq.MsmqTransport.Send(TransportMessage m, String destination) in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5f701adefe8f8\src\impl\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast.Msmq\MsmqTransport.cs:line 346
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.SendMessage(IEnumerable`1 destinations, String correlationId, MessageIntentEnum messageIntent, IMessage[] messages) in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5f701adefe8f8\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 593
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.Publish[T](T[] messages) in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5f701adefe8f8\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 343
   at Publisher.ServerEndpoint.Run() in C:\Downloads\ESB\NServiceBus\publisher\publisher\ServerEndpoint.cs:line 26
   at NServiceBus.Host.Internal.ConfigManager.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\20b5f701adefe8f8\src\host\NServiceBus.Host\Internal\ConfigurationManager.cs:line 56

Is there a timeout period after which it will try to send message to rest of subscribers, I waited quite long...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will retry.

Pulling the rug (queue) out from under a running endpoint is not a good thing to do.  In production this really should never happen.

Since you're just testing, delete the offending subscription row from the database, and restart the endpoint, and everything should be fine.

Comment: Any idea how to turn on jounaling in the queue by default i.e. when pub/sub create the queue, I tried UseJournalQueue="true" with no effect